# Possible to observe (KVO) every property of an NSObject?

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, nsobject

I'm thingking of create a base class where every change made is immediately saved to NSUserDefaults (only KVO compilant parts of course), and automatically loads whenever that type of object is instantiated (a really basic, reusable user data store).

I have no intention to provide a "list of keys"-like constant to every subclass of this object, so I'm hoping that there is an automatic way to observe every property of an object.

Any ideas how to do this? With merely public API of course.

Comment: I'm a little confused by why providing a list of keys to subclasses would be necessary or helpful in the first place, which makes me think I've maybe misunderstood your question. My understanding is that you want every instance of this class and its descendants to write / read from the plist. But then it seems like the superclass would handle all the observing and writing / reading and the subclasses would provide some set of keys that are unique to itself so that the superclass implementation would observe all relevant keys. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of properties for an object, you can save them to a dictionary in NSUserDefaults. To save each property every time it is set you can create custom setter methods for each property using this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"yourKey"] == nil) {

            NSDictionary *dict  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"yourObject" forKey:@"keyForYourObject"];
            // Add stuff to the dictionary
            [defaults setObject:dict forKey:@"yourKey"];
        }else{
            NSDictionary *dict = [defaults objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
            // Add stuff to the dictionary
             [defaults setObject:dict forKey:@"yourKey"];
        }
```

This will give you a single dictionary stored in UserDefaults with all the properties. Then to get the list of keys use the standart method:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
```

Comment: By the way, I created a root class that uses a plist file with the properties to observe, and their default values. Works like a charm, now any object subclass of this is stored automatically, and gets instantiated with the predefined default values.

Comment: Why doesn't it sound automatic? Every time you set that property in this class or a subclass, it is automatically saved and getting the keys is two lines of code. You would still have to change the plist file in pretty much the same way if you want to set the properties. Or maybe I'm misunderstood your requirements a bit :) Anyways, great to hear that you solved your problem :)